# DRY Django Bootstrap tabs

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am currently trying to implement tabbed content in Django, and for obvious reasons am trying to implement the DRY principle, but as far as I can tell there is no way to make unique content for each tab without writing it out implicitly, which will end up with something like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#readpane">Read</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#gawkpane">Gawk</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#talkpane">Talk</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#shoppane">Shop</a></li>
</ul>



<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="readpane" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="row">
            {% for post in range %}
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                      <a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">
                        <div class="">
                            <h1>{{ tab }}</h1>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris varius fermentum lacus,
                            non ornare ipsum accumsan et. Suspendisse sodales tempor viverra. Sed faucibus quis
                            ipsum eleifend laoreet. Nunc non ante condimentum ipsum tincidunt pretium. Duis varius
                            elit ut interdum imperdiet. Sed auctor est et nisi maximus, at blandit massa malesuada.
                            Nunc tempor feugiat sollicitudin. Nullam mollis varius porttitor.

                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="gawkpane" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="row">
                {% for post in range %}
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">
                            <div class="">
                                <h1>{{ tab }}</h1>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris varius fermentum lacus,
                                non ornare ipsum accumsan et. Suspendisse sodales tempor viverra. Sed faucibus quis
                                ipsum eleifend laoreet. Nunc non ante condimentum ipsum tincidunt pretium. Duis varius
                                elit ut interdum imperdiet. Sed auctor est et nisi maximus, at blandit massa malesuada.
                                Nunc tempor feugiat sollicitudin. Nullam mollis varius porttitor.

                            </div>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

which yes, is a a big, ugly wall of code. Now I may be misunderstanding how tabs and whatnot work, but the only solution I was able to find that didn't add huge layers of complexity was this

```
**Placed in templates/includes/tabs.html**

<ul class="tab-menu">
    <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab1' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab2' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab3' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>



**Placed in your page template**

{% include "includes/tabs.html" with active_tab='tab1' %}
```

But as far as I can tell that will just move the code that produces the menu into a separate file, and as this tab menu will only be on one page, I don't need that.

To summarize my question, is there a way to build the tab content differently using a single template for any tab, and passing context variables to it?

Comment: What is wrong with the current approach exactly? You can't apply DRY and have unique content at the same time

Comment: @Sayse I want to apply DRY to the thumbnails, which don't change, but allow me to change the Lorem Ipsum, which does change, if it's not possible then so be it, but it just feels so out of character to write 4 nearly identical code blocks

Comment: Not really the only thing you could possibly do is include a dictionary in your context data in the form of "tab : content block", but given that you're working with a navigation I don't think this is really feasible. Your other option perhaps is a custom template block tag but I don't have the time really to make any sort of full answer about that